# Django dynamic filter

Tags: sql, django, orm

I have a product:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
```

Features of this product, with fk to dynamic attributes:

```
class ProductFeatures(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    features_category = models.ForeignKey('FeaturesCategory')
    value = models.ForeignKey('Features')
```

Dynamic attribute name model:

```
class FeaturesCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_(u'Название'))
```

And values for each attribute:

```
class Features(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('FeaturesCategory')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_(u'Значение'))
```

Example of working all of this:

We created FeaturesCategory object - "Color", added some values to it: "Red", "Green", "Blue". And added another FeaturesCategory object - "Count" with values: "1", "2", "3"

All of this we add to product, for example:

color - red
count - 3

**Trouble, is how to filter this products ??**

```
for param in self.request.GET:
            if not param in ['pangination', 'view', 'order', 'page']:
                name, value = param.split('_')
                filters.append(
                    Q(productfeatures__features_category__title=name,
                      productfeatures__features_category__features__value=value)
                )
```

If we have two "params" to filter it doesn't work

Comment: What values are you expecting in ```request.GET```?

Comment: I'm not sure you're using `Q` right. Try doing `productfeatures__features_category__title=name, productfeatures__features_category__features__value=value` without it instead.

Comment: my problem that i generate query like this: `filter(Q(attr='Color', value='Red'), Q(attr='Count', value='5'))` If i selected two filters...

Answer (score 0):

You shoud build you Q types dynamically somethink like that:

```
 qlist = []
 for fi in filters:
        if len(fi) == 2:
            fi = fi.split('_')
            qlist.append(Q((fi[0],fi[1])))
    if qlist:
        YourModel.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, qlist))
```

Comment: my problem that i generate query like this: filter(Q(attr='Color', value='Red'), Q(attr='Count', value='5')) If i selected two filters... And of course it not select product that have attr 'color' and 'count'